# VBA macro to group all rows under one heading, headings when more than one heading exists

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a vba macro to achieve the following but do not how to implement it. Would any please provide some guidance?

Currently, the data is as follows(subitem spans from column B onwards):

```
ITEM ONE [Subitem one... ]
ITEM ONE [Subitem two ...]
ITEM ONE [Subitem three...]  
ITEM TWO [Subitem one  ...]
ITEM THREE [Subitem one...]
ITEM Three [Subitem two...]
```

The following is what the data should look like in a separate sheet:

```
ITEM ONE  
-------- 
Subitem one  
Subitem two 
Subitem three  

ITEM TWO 
-------- 
Subitem one  

ITEM THREE 
---------- 
Subitem one 
Subitem two
```

Any guidance/help will be greatly appreciated.

Edited: solution as follows:

```
  r = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
  c = Range("IU1").End(xlToLeft).Column
  a = Split(Cells(, c).Address, "$")(1)
  MsgBox "last row with data is " & r & " and last column with data is " & a & "", vbOKOnly, "LastRow and LastCol"
  rr = r + 1

  Application.Visible = False

  Range("A1:" & a & r & "").Sort Key1:=Range("B2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Sheets("owssvr(1)").Select
Sheets.Add


'by default select first record and paste in reports sheet
Sheets("owssvr(1)").Select
Range("b2").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets(1).Select
Range("b2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

   'paste header below it

Sheets("owssvr(1)").Select
Range("c1:" & a & "2").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets(1).Select
Range("b3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste



For i = 3 To r
Sheets(2).Select
'Program name is same as above, dont copy name but row starting from next col, switch to other sheet, find last row in col B, add one to last row and paste
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
        Range("C" & i & ":" & a & i & "").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets(1).Select
        'Range("b3").Select
        lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
        'if name is not same as above, copy name, find last row, add two to add a gap from prev program name, paste program name, move to next row and paste remaining cols
         Sheets(2).Select
         Range("B" & i & "").Select
         Selection.Copy

         Sheets(1).Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 2 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'copy headers
         Sheets(2).Select

         Range("c1:" & a & "1").Select
         Selection.Copy
         Sheets(1).Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'copy cells(row, col+1)
         Sheets(2).Select
         Range("C" & i & ":" & a & i & "").Select
         Selection.Copy

         Sheets(1).Select
        'Range("b3").Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If
    Next
```

Comment: I am not sure yet that I can answer this question even if I fully understood, but you should clarify one or two things: Are you trying to itemize based on numerical, alphanumeric, formatting or other criteria? Also, for which version of excel are you attempting to implement this organizing macro?

Comment: I am trying to itemize on the basis of value of cells in column A. ITEM ONE, TWO, THREE... are in col A.

Comment: Ah, I see. So the itemization would be independent of the type of value enclosed. I assume you are using excel 2007 or excel 2010?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I would just compare the value in consecutive cells, if values match(it has text only), then i will paste the rows where the headers are equal one below the other and so on. Data is already sorted on the header column.                        I am using excel 2003.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I've also noticed you don't accept many answers nor upvote answers you do accept. Please show appreciation for people who offer the help/guidance you seek. :)

Comment: @joiner Ok, this should prove interesting, assuming a generic solution for any given set of N:n to n headers to subitems. I will give it some thought. ~JOL

Comment: @Zairja: I do. If there's no comment or suggestion, i still do.

Comment: @joiner Are the subitems only in Col B or do they extend to multiple columns?

Comment: The data begins from header + one column onwards. That gets taken care of by getting the last col no. in first row - that's never going to be blank. Add some flex to the code by letting user enter the column number and start "reading" from that col onwards.

Comment: @JOL: see the solution. crude, ugly but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for can be done with a [PivotTable](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx). I'm working in Excel 2010, but 2003 should probably have the same functionality. This is how it would look like.

[image: Source Data]

[image: PivotTable]

The naive VBA approach I was going to do (which I guess you've implemented) was looping through all the items, doing comparisons, and adding them one at a time to the new worksheet. This can be made a bit more efficient if you store the initial range (of 2 columns) in an array, loop through that and store the output in a 2nd array, then copy the array back to a range.

I'm not sure how much data you have or how long that operation takes. Another alternative would be to use the macro recorder to make a PivotTable and copy the data from there to a new sheet. Here's an example, though you'd want to change the worksheet and range references to make them explicit/dynamic. The example data range is `A1:B9`.

```
Sub Example()

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R1C1:R9C2", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet4").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("item1")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("sub12")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I actually did that as the first thing and got the pivot refreshed by checking and extending the range through a button. But you know how sometimes seniors dont like to click on a simple button. And, the arrays, I have to keep track of atleast 11 arrays, very in-efficient. So i am just doing a combination of loops, cell value comparision and .offset.

Comment: +1 I wracked my mind for recursive solutions, but this is VBA =)

Answer (score 0):

your old worksheet is called yourWorksheet.
create a new worksheet:

```
set newWS = thisworkbook.workbooks.add()

dim rr as long 
rr =1

for r = startRow to yourWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    firstItem = yourWorksheet.cells(r,1).value
    newWS.cells(rr,1).value = firstItem
    rr = rr + 1
    do while firstItem = yourworksheet.cells(r,1).value
       newWS.cells(rr,1).value = yourworksheet.cells(rr,2).value 'copy all columns here
       rr = rr + 1
       r =r + 1
    loop
next r
```

rough and untested, but that's the idea.

Comment: What is firstItem - in object terms? Cell value, range, variable?

Comment: @Motes You may want to explicitly declare the variables used since joiner seems pretty new to VBA. :)

Comment: Zairja: Yea.. kind of.. I am currently putting everything in a array and and then reading and dumping from the array.. very crude approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the left command and extract the Item One, Item Two, etc.

```
Heading(row) = Left(Cells(row,"B"), 8)
```

then extract the subItem:

```
SubItem(row) = Left(Right(cells(row, "B"), 20), 10)
```

These will extract the text.

You have to get creative for THREE and FOUR.

Comment: Hey Jack, Sorry you got it wrong...  what i mean by subitems is that there is data in column B onwards, eg. b2, c2, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Sort1()
'
' Sort1 Macro
' Macro recorded 7/30/2012 by American International Group
'
'

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim lr2 As Integer
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim cdb As Long
Dim name1 As String
Dim name2 As String


n1 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a name for worksheet else click OK", Title:="Enter a name for this sheet", Default:="owssvr")
n2 = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter a name for the Report view sheet else click OK", Title:="Enter a name for Report sheet", Default:="reportView")
b = InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Column Name on which to sort data", Title:="Sort by", Default:="B")
b = UCase(b)   'convert to uppercase  e.g.c to C
asciiCol = Asc(b)   'convert to ascii          66
asciiNext = asciiCol + 1  'add one to ascii to get next column ascii code e.g. 66+1=67 to get D


sortbyColNo = 0
sortbyColNo = Range(b & "1").Column

'Rename sheets to avoid conflict
Sheets(1).name = n1

Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select

r = Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
c = Range("IU1").End(xlToLeft).Column
a = Split(Cells(, c).Address, "$")(1)
x = Split(Cells(, c).Address, "$")(2)
MsgBox "last row with data is " & r & " and last column with data is " & a & "", vbOKOnly, "LastRow and LastCol"
rr = r + 1

'Application.Visible = False

  Range("A1:" & a & r & "").Sort Key1:=Range("" & b & "2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
    xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
    DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

   Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.name = n2

'by default select first record and paste in reports sheet
Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
Range("" & b & "2").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
Range("b2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'paste header below it

Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
Range("" & Chr(asciiNext) & "1:" & a & "1").Select
With Selection
.Font.Bold = True
End With
Range("" & Chr(asciiNext) & "1:" & a & "2").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
Range("b3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


'start from row 3
For i = 3 To r
  Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
'Program name is same as above, dont copy name but row starting from next col, switch to other sheet, find last row in col B, add one to last row and paste
    If Cells(i, sortbyColNo).Value = Cells(i - 1, sortbyColNo) Then
        Range("" & Chr(asciiNext) & "" & i & ":" & a & i & "").Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
        'Range("b3").Select
        lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
        'if name is not same as above, copy name, find last row, add two to add a gap from prev program name, paste program name, move to next row and paste remaining cols
        Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
         Range("" & b & "" & i & "").Select
         Selection.Copy

       Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 2 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'copy headers
        Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select

         Range("" & Chr(asciiNext) & "1:" & a & "1").Select
         Selection.Copy
       Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         'copy cells(row, col+1)
     Sheets("" & n1 & "").Select
         Range("" & Chr(asciiNext) & i & ":" & a & i & "").Select
         Selection.Copy

        Sheets("" & n2 & "").Select
        'Range("b3").Select
         lr2 = Range("b65536").End(xlUp).Row
         Range("B" & lr2 + 1 & "").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If
    Next
 'Application.Visible = True

'formatSheet

End Sub
```